# Searching keyword through elastic search resulting ambiguous

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am trying to search the keyword of type text through elastic search. It is matching with few characters on the starting but after more than half characters of words entered, result is showing nothing.

For Ex:

1. Keyword to search is "illustrate"

The result is perfectly showing up to "illust" characters.
but when it becomes "illustr" or "illustra" or "illustrat" or "illustrate" there is zero match/hit.

2. Keyword to search is "safety"

The result is perfectly showing up to "safet" characters.
but when it becomes "safety" there is zero match/hit.

This is happening for every words which are having characters more than 4.

I have tried wildcard query for the above use case:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "field": {
        "value": "*string_to_be_search*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Anupam, I am afraid I am a bit confused by your question. Could you show the mapping,  the query you are using,  the result of the query and what you would expect to see.